# How to get_term_children output in alphabetical order?

Tags: terms

How do i get output of this in alphabetical order

```
<?php
    $termID = 5;
    $taxonomyName = 'area';
    $termchildren = get_term_children( $termID, $taxonomyName );

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($termchildren as $child) {
        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomyName );
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->name, $taxonomyName ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`get_term_children()` only outputs the term IDs, and you later get details for each term using `get_term_by()`. You can combine these queries in one using [`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) with the `child_of` argument:

```
get_terms( $taxonomyName, array( 'child_of' => $termID ) );
```

By default this sorts by name. However, it is possible that the `child_of` argument undoes the sorting. In that case you can sort it again using `usort()`. See an example at [this answer for a related problem](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16921/get-pages-not-ordering-as-it-should/16960#16960).

Comment: This still works in 2019. Very helpful answer! :)